# Netfilter Crashes when editing TCP payload

Tags: c, linux-kernel, netfilter

I have a Netfilter module that captures TCP packets.

I then access the data payload, and then replace some of the words. However, it 
occasionally error's and then hangs up. Then, packets can no longer go through...

Only TCP packets with Port 80 go through.

[image: Error]

Data is set by  `data = (char *)((unsigned char *)tcp_header + (tcp_header->doff * 4));`

```
while(strstr(data, "the") != NULL){
    data = replace_str(data, "the", "REDACTED", 0);
    //censors the word "the" and replaces with "REDACTED"
    }
    printk("Port 80 Web Data:\n %s \n",data);
```

Comment: What is `replace_str` function? According to its name, it should replace one string with another, but what if lengths of replaced strings differs?

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing a string with a longer string. This may overflow the socket buffer structure. This is likely to be the cause of the crash.

Answer (score -1):

Also, remember to recalculate the TCP  checksum once the packet data is changed with new data.